# Azure ADLS Gen2 API to delete file

Tags: azure, curl, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, talend

I am trying to delete a file from Azure ADLS storage through Talend. Upon my checking, I couldn't find any option to connect to ADLS from Talend and delete a file or folder.
As another option, I am trying to run a cURL command from Talend shell to delete using the ADLS API.

**

- ADLS Gen2 API reference

**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/delete

I have created a SAS token from the Storage account.

My cURL command looks like below.

`curl -X DELETE -H "x-ms-date: Thu, 28 May 2020 05:51:37 GMT" https://account10.dfs.core.windows.net/testfolder/test1/test2/?<SAS Token>`

I am trying to delete the files inside test2 folder.

When running, I am getting the below error.

{"error":{"code":"InvalidUri","message":"The request URI is invalid..

Can anyone help on the same.

Thanks
Sathya

Comment: I noticed that you have a trailing slash (`/`) in your path. Can you try by removing that? Try something like `https://account10.dfs.core.windows.net/testfolder/test1/test2?<SAS Token>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** a sample command to delete non-empty directory(Note: in this sample, replace the **?** with **&** just before the sasToekn):

```
curl -X DELETE -H "x-ms-date: Thu, 28 May 2020 05:51:37 GMT" "https://account10.dfs.core.windows.net/testfolder/test1/test2?recursive=true&sv=2019-10-10&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupx&se=2020-05-29T08:50:28Z&st=2020-05-29T00:50:28Z&spr=https&sig=xxx"
```

Test result:

[image]

---

As Mantri mentioned in the comment, there is a redundant '/' after test2 in the url. You should remove it.

Besides that, you should note the following 2 considerations:

1.If you want to delete a **non-empty folder**, you should add `recursive=true` in the url. The curl command like below:

```
curl -X DELETE -H "x-ms-date: Thu, 28 May 2020 05:51:37 GMT" "https://account10.dfs.core.windows.net/testfolder/test1/test2?recursive=true&sasToken"
```

2.If you want to delete a file, use the command like below:

```
curl -X DELETE -H "x-ms-date: Thu, 28 May 2020 05:51:37 GMT" "https://account10.dfs.core.windows.net/testfolder/test1/test2/aa.txt?sasToken"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I too tried the command but it gives me error. {"error":{"code":"MissingRequiredQueryParameter","message":"A query parameter that's mandatory for this request is not specified.\

Comment: I can able to delete the particular text file within the directory, but I need to delete all the files within the directory. The command which I am using is, C:\WINDOWS\system32>curl -X DELETE -H "x-ms-date: Thu, 28 May 2020 05:51:37 GMT" "https://account1.dfs.core.windows.net/testaccount/test1/test2?recursive=true?<SAS Token>"
{"error":{"code":"MissingRequiredQueryParameter","message":"A query parameter that's mandatory for this request is not specified.\

Comment: @Sathya, I see your command, when delete a folder, please remove ? just before the sasToken.

Comment: if I remove the ? it erros out as Server failed to authenticate. I can able to delete the folder sucessfully, but I need a command to delete all the files inside the folder and not the folder

Comment: I used wildcards but not sucessfull

Comment: @Sathya, please see the updated answer with the command to delete a non-empty directory. It's working at my side.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, yes, it works but my requirement is only to delete the files inside a directory and not to delete the actual folder. As per your example, if I have 10 csv formatted files inside the sample folder, I need a command to delete only the *.csv files and not the folder

Comment: @Sathya, just remove the files, but not the directory. I'll give it a try and update you later:).

Comment: @Sathya, after some research, I found it's impossible. Even in the azure portal, I tried to batch delete all the files, I found that it's actually delete them one by one by using the delete file api. So you should delete these files one by one, or delete the files and the folder first, then use the create path api to create the folder again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I couldn't find anything to delete only the files and not the folder. Thanks again for your effort

Comment: @Sathya, you can consider the workaround as mentioned in my comments. And if the answer is helpful, could you please help accept it as answer? Thanks.